# How to remove "index.php?" from HTACCESS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have url like this:

www.site.com/index.php?/genero/aventura/av/

But I would like this to be my new url:

site.com/genero/aventura/av/

I used the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php\?/(.*)$ site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

but only returns me: site.com/index.php?/genero/aventura/av/

This is my latest & full version:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|ver_capitulo\.html|google3436eb8eea8b8d6e\.html|BingSiteAuth\.xml |portadas|public|mp3|css|favicon\.ico|js|plantilla|i|swf|plugins|player\.swf|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|css|js|i|feed|portadas|robots\.txt|BingSiteAuth\.xml|plugins|i|mp3|favicon\.ico|pluginslist\.xml|google3436eb8eea8b8d6e\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#DirectoryIndex index.php
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} http://www.page.com/index\.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ http://page.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

#DirectoryIndex index.php
#RewriteEngine On
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The `Host:` name does not contain a trailing slash. And the query string is not available as RewriteRule path, but only [in `%{QUERY_STRING}`](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString). Your rules, btw, only redirect to the intended new URL scheme. Unless you also process the then incoming normalized paths, the index.php handler script won't be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|css|js|i|feed|portadas|robots\.txt|BingSiteAuth\.xml|plugins|i|mp3|favicon\.ico|pluginslist\.xml|google3436eb8eea8b8d6e\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I try in this way so that it contains the www:

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} www.page.com/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ page.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

but still has not been solved

Comment: Why did you make in `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} www.page.com/index\.php` instead of what I suggested?

Comment: You also use your suggestion, and gave me the same result, try removing www. and also index.php? because when I try to remove the www. I just goes to index.php?, I remove both (www and index.php?).

Comment: Paste your latest & full .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Now you can see the code above, I posted the part

Comment: see updated code, copy/paste it as it (don't change).

Comment: The result is www.page.com/?/section/1, but I need to remove the "www" and "?" in this update so that it is http:// page.com/section/1

Comment: Your question title says: **How to remove “index.php?” from HTACCESS** Don't add more questions via comments. Accept this answer and create a new question for other problems.

Comment: Oh, right, thank you very much for your help anubhava

Comment: You should mark the answer accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Sorry I was offline, your answer is useful for the question asked. Already marked you for being very helpful.